# Почему компилятор жалуется на malloc?

Tags: c

Объясните пожалуйста, а как иначе?

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS"); 
    int i, n, *mas;
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    printf("Введите размер массива: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    srand(time(0));
    mas = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    printf("Сгенерированный массив:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mas[i] = rand() % 100; // диапазон случайных чисед от 0 до 100
        printf("%d ", mas[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    free(mas);
    return 0;

    getchar(); 

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Потому что вы компилируете не C, а C++, в котором `void *` надо приводить явно к `int *`.

В Visual Studio, чтобы показать компилятору, что это программа на C, сделайте расширение у файла с кодом `.c`.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` возвращает тип `void *`, а вы хотите массив интов, то есть `int *`.
Вы можете просто явно указать, чем будет являться ваш массив `mas`:

```
 mas = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: В C этого не требуется. Проблема ТС'а в том, что он компилирует код как C++, а не как C.